# Spring controller null object ID

Tags: spring, null, thymeleaf

When the user goes to *recipe/new* it sends a RecipeCommand object, then after the user sets the information and *Recipe Ingredients* and *Directions*, *RecipeCommand* objects gets send to *recipe/new/ingredients*. I convert it to a recipe object then save it and return it. Then I send an *Ingredients Wrapper* which has N RecipeCommands (depends the number the user set at Recipe Ingredients) and the RecipeCommand again and return to *recipe/recipe_add_ingredients*. This leads to *recipe/new/{recipeId}/ingredients/directions*. Then I take the IngredientsWrapper and add every IngredientCommand object to the RecipeCommand. The problem is that the object has a null ID even though I've added it into the database and it shows that it has the ID of 2. Here is the code:
add_recipe

```
<form th:object="${recipe}" th:action="@{/recipe/new/ingredients}"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}">
        <div class="add-recipe-container">
            <div class="add-recipe-inputs-container">
                <div class="add-recipe-inputs">
                    <ul class="add-recipe-inputs-list">
                        <li>
                            <label for="recipeName">Recipe Name </label>
                            <input id="recipeName" name="recipeName" th:field="*{recipeName}"  type="text">
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <label for="cookTime">Cook Time</label>
                            <input th:field="*{recipeCookTime}"  placeholder="Without minutes" type="number">
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label for="prepTime">Prep Time</label>
                            <input th:field="*{recipePrepTime}"  placeholder="Without minutes" type="number">
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label for="servings">Servings</label>
                            <input th:field="*{recipeServings}"  type="number">
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="add-recipe-options-container">
                <div class="add-recipe-options">
                    <ul class="add-recipe-options-list">
                        <li>
                            <label>Difficulty</label>
                            <select th:field="*{difficulty}" id="difficulty.id">
                            <option th:each="difficultyEach : ${T(com.vio.spring5.domain.Difficulty).values()}"
                                    th:value="${difficultyEach.id}"
                                    th:text="${difficultyEach.name}">
                            </option>
                            </select>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label>Category</label>
                            <select th:field="*{recipeCategory}" id="recipeCategory.id">
                            <option th:each="category : ${T(com.vio.spring5.domain.RecipeCategory).values()}"
                                    th:value="${category.id}"
                                    th:text="${category.name}">
                                    </option>
                            </select>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <label for="ingredientsAmount">Ingredients</label>
                            <input th:field="*{recipeIngredientsAmount}"  type="number">
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label for="directionsAmount">Directions</label>
                            <input th:field="*{recipeDirectionsAmount}"  type="number">
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <label for="">Image</label>
                            <input th:field="*{image}" id="imagefile" name="imagefile" type="file" class="file">
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <button type="submit" class="next-page-button">Next</button>
    </form>
```

add_ingredient

```
  <form  th:object="${ingredientsWrapper}" th:action="@{'/recipe/new/' + ${recipe.getId()} + '/ingredients/directions'}" method="get">
        <div class="add-recipe-container">
           <ul class="recipe-many">
            <li th:each="ingredientInputs, iter : ${ingredientsWrapper.ingredientsWrapperSet}">
                <ul class="add-recipe-ingredients-list">
                            <li>
                                <label for="">Amount</label>
                                <input th:field="*{ingredientsWrapper[__${iter.index}__].amount}" type="number">
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <label for="">Unit</label>
                                <select th:field="*{ingredientsWrapper[__${iter.index}__].unitOfMeasure}">
                                    <option th:each="unit : ${unitOfMeasure}"
                                            th:value="${unit.id}"
                                              th:text="${unit.unitName}">Test</option>
                                </select>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <label for="">Ingredient Name</label>
                                <input th:field="*{ingredientsWrapper[__${iter.index}__].ingredientName}" type="text">
                            </li>
                        </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>       
        </div>
    <button type="submit" class="add-recipe">Add Recipe</button>
    </form>
```

add_directions

```
    <form th:object="${directionsWrapper}" th:action="@{'/recipe/new/' + ${recipe.id} + '/ingredients/directions'}" method="post">
        <div class="add-directions-container">
            <ul class="directions-many">
                <li th:each="directions, iter : ${directionsWrapper.directionsWrapperList}">
                    <label>Step: </label>
                    <textarea th:field="*{directionsWrapper[__${iter.index}__].directions}" cols="40" rows="3"></textarea>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <button type="submit" class="add-recipe">Add Recipe</button>
    </form>
```

Controllers

```
/*
 * Send a RecipeCommand object to front
 */
@GetMapping(value = "/recipe/new")
public String newRecipe(Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("recipe", new RecipeCommand());

    return "recipe/recipe_add";
}

/*
 * Send the recipe wrapper
 * To do: throw exception and validation
 * 
 */

@GetMapping(value = "/recipe/new/ingredients")
public String addIngredients(@ModelAttribute("recipe") RecipeCommand recipe, BindingResult bidingResult, Model model) {

    recipeService.saveRecipeCommand(recipe);

    IngredientsWrapper wrapper = new IngredientsWrapper();
    addIngredientsCommandObjects(wrapper, recipe.getRecipeIngredientsAmount());

    model.addAttribute("unitOfMeasureSet", uomService.findAll());
    model.addAttribute("ingredientsWrapper", wrapper);
    model.addAttribute("recipe", recipe);


    return "recipe/recipe_add_ingredients";

}

/*
 * to do: validate
 */

@GetMapping(value = "/recipe/new/{recipeId}/ingredients/directions")
public String addDirections (@PathVariable String recipeId,
                             @ModelAttribute("ingredientsWrapper") IngredientsWrapper wrapper, Model model) {

    RecipeCommand recipe = recipeService.findRecipeCommandById(Long.valueOf(recipeId));

    wrapper.ingredientsWrapperSet
        .iterator()
        .forEachRemaining(ingredient -> recipe.addIngredient(ingredient));

    recipeService.updateRecipeCommandIngredients(recipe);

    DirectionsWrapper directionsWrapper = new DirectionsWrapper();
    addDirectionsCommandObjects(directionsWrapper,      recipe.getRecipeDirectionsAmount());
    model.addAttribute("directionsWrapper", directionsWrapper);
    model.addAttribute("recipe", recipe);

    return "recipe/recipe_add_directions";

}

/*
 * to do: validate
 */

@PostMapping(value = "/recipe/new/{recipeId}/ingredients/directions/")
public String addRecipe(@PathVariable String recipeId,
                        @ModelAttribute("directionsWrapper") DirectionsWrapper wrapper) {

        RecipeCommand recipe = recipeService.findRecipeCommandById(Long.valueOf(recipeId));

        wrapper.directionsWrapperList
            .iterator()
            .forEachRemaining(directions -> recipe.addDirections(directions));

        recipeService.updateRecipeCommandDirections(recipe);

        return "redirect:/browse";

    }
```

Comment: Forgot to add the method which adds the objects to the wrappers

Comment: By "having null ID" I mean, when I call "recipe/new/{recipeId}/ingredients/directions", I get "recipe/new/null/ingredients/directions"