# Thymeleaf select sets null

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I'm trying to set the ingredient's unit of measure, but it sets their ID's to null. The object I send is a wrapper that contains IngredientsCommand objects.

```
<select th:field="*{ingredientsWrapper[__${iter.index}__].unitOfMeasure}" name="unitOfMeasure.id">
   <option value="NULL"></option>
   <option th:each="unit : ${unitOfMeasureSet}"
        th:value="${unit.id}"
        th:text="${unit.unitName}">Test
   </option>
</select>
```

>

```
@Getter @Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class IngredientsCommand {

private Long Id;
private String ingredientName;
private Long recipeId;
private BigDecimal amount;
private String countryOfOrigin;
private BigDecimal ingredientCost;
private RecipeCommand recipe;
private UnitOfMeasureCommand unitOfMeasure;
}
```

>

```
@Getter @Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UnitOfMeasureCommand {

private Long id;
private String unitName;

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring controller null object ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49559663/spring-controller-null-object-id)

Comment: [It has](https://gyazo.com/65f93141cbdc6fa6d92a6689b0b261c3). That's the command object. It will get converted. [The units](https://gyazo.com/a5250f05deb4e7ff843fd0d23fa35d0a) are already added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hadn't autowired the unit of measure converter when it converts from command to ingredient. I've also changed from `th:field="*{ingredientsWrapper[__${iter.index}__].unitOfMeasure}"` to `th:field="*{ingredientsWrapper[__${iter.index}__].unitOfMeasure.id}"` and it works now. Thanks for the help.